# Understanding Java code for a binary tree implementation

Tags: java, variables, binary-tree

```
class Tree 
{
  public final int mVal;
  public Tree mLeft;
  public Tree mRight;
  public Tree(int val) // enter code here
  {
    mVal = val;
  }
}
```

I have a Java code implementing the binary tree data structure. I am new to Java so this might be a basic question. I don't understand why the variable type here is 'Tree'. I could not find it on web hence asking here. I might post further questions to understand whole code. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Because it will point to a node which is of type `Tree`

Comment: "I don't understand why the variable type here is 'Tree'" -- What do you think it should be?

Comment: integer or double, depending on what we intend to enter in the nodes.

Comment: The class is poorly named. It should be named `Node`, `TreeNode` or anything alike. It's not a _tree_, but a _node_ in a _tree_.

Comment: @NishantJain you already have "whatever we intend to enter in the nodes" as `mVal` and that is an `int` in this case. `mLeft` and `mRight` are the left and right subtrees respectively. Read up [binary trees on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) and maybe you will understand its  recursive nature?